# dayname(curdate()) NOT working in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This sql works in phpmyadmin but not working in codeigniter php

```
function getProgramsHomepage(){
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select("p_name,p_start");
    $this->db->where('p_channel', 'tv');
    $this->db->where('p_day', DAYNAME(CURDATE()));
    $this->db->order_by('id','asc');
    //$this->db->limit($limit);
    $Q = $this->db->get('programs');
    if($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DAYNAME(CURDATE())` will try to execute the PHP functions `CURDATE` and `DAYNAME`, you need to pass them as strings in a way that CI will not escape. This should do it:

```
$this->db->where('p_day = DAYNAME(CURDATE())');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write 'DAYNAME(CURDATE())' , as a string

Comment: i did "DAYNAME(CURDATE())" still no luck

Comment: what's the output of
print_r($this->db->last_query());