# how to get day from mysql with codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I need to take my date to sunday, monday, tuesday .... from my databse, currently i getting the date from the databse, how can i convert it to day (like sunday, monday)

```
$start_date = $data['start_date'];
    $end_date = $data ['end_date'];
    $student_id = $data['student_id'];

    $where_condition = ['sa.school_id' => $school_id, 'sa.student_id' => $student_id];
    $this->db
    ->select('sa.id, sa.date, sa.attendance_type, sa.reason')
    ->from('student_attendance sa')
    ->join('student st', 'st.id = sa.student_id AND st.school_id = sa.school_id', 'left')
    ->where($where_condition)
    ->where('sa.date >=', $start_date)
    ->where('sa.date <=', $end_date);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;
```

and this is my result when i run my query

```
[{"id":"2","date":"2017-07-03","attendance_type":"absent","reason":""},{"id":"3","date":"2017-07-04","attendance_type":"present","reason":""}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Day Name from Date in query

Try example :

s_date formate must be year-month-day)

```
SELECT DAYNAME( s_date ) AS DAY FROM `Table_name`
```

put that DAYNAME() function in the query

Comment: @Midhun related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041230/daynamecurdate-not-working-in-codeigniter-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use in PHP pass date you are getting from DB in place of '2017-07-03'

```
$get_day = strtotime('2017-07-03');
echo $day = date('l', $get_day);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the name of the day with mysql function `DAYNAME()` if you pass any date it will return you the name of the day f or eg `SELECT DAYNAME('2013-01-01') as day` will return you `Tuesday`, so accordingly you can use this function in your query eg `select sa.id, sa.date, DAYNAME(sa.date), sa.attendance_type, sa.reason from student_attendance`;

Answer (score 0):

DayName(Date) As Day 
You can refer 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayname-function.php